# Full screen effect on jw player 6

Tags: jwplayer

I want to achive this effect - http://partyongeorge.ca/template/index6.php

I use wordpress and the jw player ( version 6.5.3609 ) is into a div called screen , the css of the screen is

```
#screen {
color:#FFF;
margin:0 0 20px;
/*position:relative;*/
/*overflow: hidden;*/
background: #333 url(images/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Im strugling for the past week to make it work but i just dont have the neccesary skills.

Comment: Could you show what have you tried and what undesired effects you got?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: yes @Ethan i have created a site for testing and better feedback video16(dot)com

Comment: A little confused. I see a player here - http://video16.com/?p=5, it works fine. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: im trying to make the player mimic the full screen effect, the player should resize to 100% width and 100% height, like here http://partyongeorge.ca/template/index6.php  when you click full screen the player goes 100% width and 100% height.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using

```
#screen{
    position: fixed;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

If it is not suits your requirement, provide me a link i can help you i think. I experienced same problem